# I have 2 different NodeJs Servers (A, B), How I can call Server A endpoints inside Server B endpoints?

Tags: node.js

I have an Update Endpoint which update users DB inside server A, I want this endpoint call another Endpoint in Server B to update accounts DB

Comment: You can use libraries like axios and request

Comment: By endpoint you mean Http? Just use the bultin http or https module https://nodejs.dev/learn/making-http-requests-with-nodejs or use your favourite library. There are plenty of tutorials out there

Answer (score 0):

1. Add env variable which is pointing to server B
2. Create a small module to make a Http call with [pure, built-in Node API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback)
3. Execute a method of fn from created module during handling request in Server A

Do not forget properly log all invocation results to make your life esier!=)

Answer (score 0):

#### You have two services:

`Service A` to update users.

`Service B` to update accounts.

Do you want to call both endpoints at once?

*so here are few solutions:*

1. Use `PUB/SUB` using Redis, bull, or bee-queue.
2. You can call service B endpoint from service A using rest client like axios, got
3. you can save to accounts DB directly from the service A.

Answer (score 0):

You can create microservices then create you private api Key in .env in Server A and you sevice is created in Server B is providing you a data. Like in the comment above said you can use libraries like fetch or axios and while you are sending http request you need to pass API_KEY in headers

```
var http = require('http');    
var options = {
  host: 'http://localhost',
  path: '/ServerB_API',
  port: '28017',
  headers: {'custom': 'Custom Header Demo works', 'API_KEY': 'Some Secret Key'}
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = ''
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

var req = http.request(options, callback);
req.end();
```

And in response you can get response but before that that check if API_KEY matches your .env API_KEY they should be same because no other api can acces you services.

```
if(res.headers['API_KEY'] && (res.headers['API_KEY'] !== process.env.API_KEY)({
   throw 'Invalid api key';
}
```